# compare Javascript scope

Tags: javascript, scope

The following segment:

```
var obj = {
    name:'Tom',
    sayHello:function() {
        console.log("hello," + this.name);
    }
}
var name = 'Kevin';

var method = obj.sayHello;
method();
```

will get the output:

```
hello,undefined
```

but, if change `var name = 'Kevin';` to `name = 'Kevin';` The output will be `hello,Kevin`. Why they are different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two halves to the answer:

1. When you use `var method = obj.sayHello;`, you are decoupling the function from `obj`. When you invoke the a method without giving it an explicit object, (ie, `method()` instead of `obj.sayHello()`), JavaScript sets `this` to the global object, `window`.
2. When you define a variable using `var name = 'Kevin'`, you're creating a local variable with function scope. When you define a variable using `name = 'Kevin'`, you're creating a global variable, attached to the global object, `window`. This is identical to writing `window.name = 'Kevin'`.

These two things combine to mean that, inside `sayHello`, `this` is `window` and `this.name` is `Kevin`.

To solve this, you need to use `bind`, which returns a copy of your method with its context fixed to the object provided as an argument to `bind`:

```
var method = obj.sayHello;
new_method = method.bind(obj);
new_method(); // hello, Tom
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    sayHello:function() {
        console.log("hello," + this.name);
    }
```

`this` in this function refers to the global object. When you change `var name = 'Kevin';` to `name = 'Kevin';`, `name` variable is set in the global object. Since, `name` is set in global and `this` is global, `this.name` refers to `Kevin` and it prints `hello,Kevin`.

Answer (score 1):

How you call a function determines the value of `this` in the method.  In your way of calling:

```
var method = obj.sayHello;
method();
```

You are losing the `obj` reference to `this` inside of your invocation of `sayHello()` so `this` is set to the global object or undefined, not set to `obj`.  Thus, the errors you are getting.

When you do this:

```
var method = obj.sayHello;
```

All, it does it put a reference to the `sayHello` function in the `method` variable.  Nowhere is anything to do with `obj` stored in `method`.  So, when you then call `method()`, there is no object reference at all so instead of `obj.sayHello()` which causes `this` to be set to `obj`, you're just calling `sayHello()` all by itself which does not set the value of `this` to `obj`.

---

There are multiple ways to fix it.

**1) Helper Function.**

```
var method = function() {obj.sayHello()};
method();
```

**2) Use `.bind()`**

Here `.bind()` will create a helper function for you.

```
var method = obj.sayHello.bind(obj);
method();
```

**3) Change `sayHello()` method**

You can change the `sayHello()` method so it doesn't use the `this` pointer (which works fine if it is a singleton object, but not if there are multiple instances):

```
sayHello:function() {
    console.log("hello," + obj.name);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword can be tricky to get.

If you call `obj.sayHello`, the `this` keyword will refer to `obj`.
When you write `method = obj.sayHello` that the same thing that writing:

```
window.method = function() { console.log("hello," + this.name); }
```

The `this` keyword will now refer to `window`.
That's why when you reference a variable having `name` for its name, you write `window.name` which can be found by your function.